# Computer program to solve a system of polynomial equations over a finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, computer-algebra, mathematical-software

I have a set of polynomial equations for which I want to know the solutions (actually really the number of solutions). It would be great if I could get a computer to do it, but I'm not sure exactly which programs will do things over finite fields. I surmise that Macaulay 2 may be able to do something like this, but I'm not quite sure how.

Answer (score 7):

Magma. 
http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/htmlhelp/text1282.htm#12832

You can also do it in Sage or Pari/GP with a bit of programming.

Comment: While you're here, let me ask: Is there a command to count points without listing 
them? Of course, I can get the length of a list, but I am thinking about situations 
where the list would be very long and I could save time by not generating it. For a 
trivial example, something that could tell me that A^n has q^n points without 
taking time proportional to q^n.

Comment: I think you do this for curves but not for general varieties. 

Answer (score 3):

There is a package for doing this in Macaulay 2 also: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.3.1/share/doc/Macaulay2/RationalPoints/html/index.html

You might have to download the file and load it.

It doesn't seem to have any shortcuts for just producing the number of points though, so I guess you can compare this with the one from magma to see which is faster.